# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class - Kotlin Object

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, executable-jar, fatjar

I have a multi modular Gradle project with Kotlin.
One of the modules have the main method and dependencies to others. I need to create an executable jar from this module. So I have tried to do that by creating a Jar task like this

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'my_package.RunnerKt'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.filter{ it.exists() }.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

And also I tried the [Shadow Gradle Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).
In both cases the fat jar is created as expected, it seems to have all my classes and dependencies. But when I run the jar with `java -jar` I get the following error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class my_kotlin_object_class` where `my_kotlin_object_class` is just a kotlin `object` with some variables.

In the stacktrace there are no other exceptions which could cause this one, so seems it just has a problem with this class itself. When I look into the jar, I can see this file there.

I don't understand is this a problem with kotlin object itself and executable jars, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

So actually there was another exception behind this one!
The strange thing was that as long as the class that the exception was happening in was a `Kotlin Object` I was not able to see the real exception in stacktrace (I don't know why).
As soon as I changed the `object` with a `class` I saw the real cause of the error. I fixed it, changed back it to `object` and everything worked as expected.

So the problem itself was specific to my code, but someone might benefit from it as well.
Actually in that object I was reading some configuration files with `val url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("path_to_file")`
these files were in the `resources\configs` directory of my module. And after packing them into fat jar they were in the root of the **jar** inside **configs** folder.

The **path_to_file** was a relative path starting with `./` e.g. `./configs/my_config.json` which is working fine when I run the project in IntelliJ, but inside fat jar it was failing to load the files.
The solution, very surprisingly for me, was just to remove the `./` prefix from the path leaving it just `configs/my_config.json`. And everything worked as expected.

Comment: What was the fix you implemented after changing from object to class?  Is it useful for general knowledge, or a problem with your code?

Comment: It was a problem with my code, but may be it can be useful to someone else, so I will edit my answer and include it as well